# Double escape characters in elisp regex patterns

Tags: elisp, emacs24

```
(regexp-opt '("this" "that"))
```

returns,

```
"\\(?:th\\(?:at\\|is\\)\\)
```

Why there are double backward slashes everywhere in this elisp regex. Doesn't elisp regex use single backward slash?

And, ? symbol is a postfix operator in regex patterns which means it acts upon the characters that precedes it..(http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special). but here, there are no expressions before the ? operator. so, what does 
`(?:th\\` 
part mean in this regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is part of the regexp syntax. But to preserve it as part of a regexp string, you need to protect it with another backslash, as documented in the [syntax for strings documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html#Syntax-for-Strings):

*'Likewise, you can include a backslash by preceding it with another backslash, like this: "this \\ is a single embedded backslash".'*

As for the `?:` construct, it's how you specify a non-capturing or "shy" group:

*"A shy group serves the first two purposes of an ordinary group (controlling the nesting of other operators), but it does not get a number, so you cannot refer back to its value with ‘\digit’. Shy groups are particularly useful for mechanically-constructed regular expressions, because they can be added automatically without altering the numbering of ordinary, non-shy groups."*

It's documented as part of the [regexp backslash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash). As the passage quoted above explains, it's useful in functions like `regexp-opt` for grouping patterns without creating capture groups.